# How exactly do differential forms generalize line integrals?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms, line-integrals

On *Calculus on Manifolds* Spivak claims

> [T]he integral of a $1$-form over a $1$-chain is called a line integral.

Which seems to imply that line integrals (as they are usually defined) can be written in terms of $1$-forms and $1$-chains (and vice-versa).

---

Say I have $1$-chain $c:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and a vector field $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. We may compute the line integral of $F$ over $c$ as
$$\int_cF:=\int_0^1F(c(t))\cdot c'(t)\ dt.$$

What $1$-form $\alpha$ allows me to write the integral above as
$$\int_c\alpha \ ?$$

Similarly, given a $1$-form $\alpha$ and a $1$-chain $c$, what vector field $F$ allows me to write $\int_c\alpha$ in terms of $F$?

Comment: $\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^nF_i\,dx^i$ is the 1-form you’re looking for, and $c$ is still the same 1-chain you wrote. This is already suggested in the classical notation $\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{dr}=\sum_{i=1}F_i\,dx^i$.

Comment: actually your terminology is slightly off: a map $c:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}^n$ is a singular 1-cube, while a 1-chain is a formal sum of such 1-cubes (so the $c$ you wrote is not the most general type of 1-chain).

Comment: @peek-a-boo how would one show the intergals are equal though?

Comment: It’s a matter of definitions: what is the definition of $\int_c\alpha$? Now do a 1-2 lines worth of calculations at most.

Comment: Spivak's book is tough going unless you have a fair amount of prior experience with the material. You might look at some of my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile) on the material you're interested in.